# How to send current page number in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTable to display huge amount of data in a table. I am getting data page wise on Ajax request like this:

```
var pageNo = 1;
$('#propertyTable').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "${contextPath}/admin/getNextPageData/"+pageNo+"/"+10,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "propertyId" },
        { "data": "propertyname" },
        { "data": "propertyType" },
        { "data": "hotProperties" },
        { "data": "address" },
        { "data": "state" },
        { "data": "beds" },
        { "data": "city" },
        { "data": "zipCode" }
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        pageNo = this.fnPagingInfo().iPage+1;
        alert(pageNo); // this alerts correct page
     }
} );
```

and here is the spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getNextPageData/{pageNo}/{propertyPerPage}")
public @ResponseBody PropertyDatatableDto getNextPageData(@PathVariable Integer pageNo, @PathVariable Integer propertyPerPage) {
    System.out.println("called");
    System.out.println(pageNo); // this always prints 1, what i need is current pageNo here


    PropertyDatatableDto datatableDto = new PropertyDatatableDto();
    //datatableDto.setDraw(1);
    datatableDto.setRecordsTotal(100);
    datatableDto.setRecordsFiltered(100);
    datatableDto.setData(adminService.getAllPropertyList());
    return datatableDto;
}
```

The problem is that when I change page in table it alerts correct `pageNo` on page (in JavaScript), but in spring controller I am always getting the initial value assigned to the variable `pageNo` and not the current page number.

How do I pass `pageNo` dynamically to spring controller? Any help is appreciated.

### Edit:

I updated JavaScript like this:

```
    var oSettings = $('#propertyTable').dataTable().fnSettings();
    var currentPageIndex = Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength) + 1; 

$('#propertyTable').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "${contextPath}/admin/getNextPageData/"+currentPageIndex+"/"+10,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "propertyId" },
        { "data": "propertyname" },
        { "data": "propertyType" },
        { "data": "hotProperties" },
        { "data": "address" },
        { "data": "state" },
        { "data": "beds" },
        { "data": "city" },
        { "data": "zipCode" }
    ]
});
```

But it's giving me an error:

> DataTables warning: table id=propertyTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

DataTables already sends parameters `start` and `length` in the request that you can use to calculate page number, see [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

If you still need to have the URL structure with the page number, you can use the code below:

```
"ajax": {
   "data": function(){
      var info = $('#propertyTable').DataTable().page.info();

      $('#propertyTable').DataTable().ajax.url(
          "${contextPath}/admin/getNextPageData/"+(info.page + 1)+"/"+10
      );
   }
},
```

Comment: FYI, the calculation to get the page number is: `data.start / data.length + 1`

Answer (score 3):

"Untested"
Edit: Added "retrieve": true in options to retrieve the table instance (v1.10), checked if table exists. Changed fnSettings to setting() for datatable v1.10.

You can try to read from the datatable settings and then from settings read [_iDisplayStart](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayStart) and [_iDisplayLength](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayLength) , then calculate current page index as follows:

```
var currentPageIndex  = 1;
//Is datatable already initialized? 
if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#propertyTable' ) ) {
//Get the current settings and calculate current page index
    var oSettings = $('#propertyTable').dataTable({"retrieve": true}).settings();
    currentPageIndex = Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength) + 1;


}
```

then in ajax call pass currentPageIndex:

```
 "ajax": "${contextPath}/admin/getNextPageData/"+currentPageIndex +"/"+10,
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but its throwing some error saying cannot reinitialize DataTable

Comment: Which version of datatable are you using ?

Comment: 1.10.0, also i updated my question. please check where i am doing wrong. thanks.

Comment: Thank You @SSA. But as Gyrocode.com's answer is working fine for me, so i didn't check your updated code. It may work though, Thanks Anyway!

Answer (score 0):

use this code gives a better result

```
   fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    var info = table.page.info();

    if (
      i < info.start ||
      i >= info.end
    ) {
      i = info.start;
    }

    $("td:first", nRow).html(i + 1);
    i += 1;
    return nRow;
  },
```

Comment: Please explain why using this code gives a better result

Answer (score 0):

Instead reload the datatable using `$("YourDataTableId").DataTable().ajax.reload()` , we can use below code to send current page number at server side to load data of that page number.

```
var currentDataTable = $("YourDataTableId").DataTable();
let currentPage = currentDataTable.page() >= 0 ? currentDataTable.page() : 0;
currentDataTable.page(currentPage).draw(false);
```

along with this code we have to use the below setting in datatable -

```
$("YourDataTableId").DataTable({
        "stateSave": true, // to save the current page
});`
```